# Integração entre R e HTML

Tags: html, r

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para exportar os resultados de um código em R para um painel desenvolvido em HTML?

Comment: São dados de uma tabela, resultados numéricos, gráficos? Coloque um exemplo do que precisa. Utiliza Rstudio?

Comment: Seria para expor resultados numéricos como KPIs e talvez alguns gráficos. O objetivo seria gerar uma dashboard html obtendo dados de cálculos efetuados em R.

Comment: O R obteria os dados de um banco de dados, faria os cálculos e a dashboard html exporia os resultados na forma de KPIs e gráficos.

Comment: O modo mais simples seria utilizar a função RNotebook no Rstudio. Senão, precisa organizar seu código como RMarkdown, exportando para html os dados de interesse e ocultado as informações desnecessárias na exibição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá para fazer uns dashboards bons com o pacote `flexdashboard`. Vou colocar um exemplo abaixo, mas é claro que você pode fazer coisas muito mais complexas, por exemplo: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/cran-gauge/

Primeiro, instale o pacote usando

```
install.packages("flexdashboard")
```

Depois rode isso aqui para criar um template de arquivo.

```
rmarkdown::draft("dashboard.Rmd", template = "flex_dashboard", package = "flexdashboard")
```

Ele vai criar um arquivo chamado `dashboard.Rmd` com um código template, bem aprecido com o abaixo. Lá você pode colocar o seu código para gerar os gráficos da forma que quiser.

Por exemplo:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$drat)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
plot(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$cyl)
```

### Chart C

```{r}
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$drat)
```
````

Em seguida, aperte `ctrl` + `shift` + `K` ou clique no botão `knit` no RStudio. Isso gerará um html, igual ao abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode configurar praticamente tudo. A documentação é bem boa.
Leia mais aqui: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/index.html